# Allow HID control for the sandboxed app

Tags: xcode, sandbox

We're trying to sandbox our app to submit it to the Mac App Store (for the first time). It makes hard use of the lower level Carbon APIs and cannot operate the other way.

When I enabled the sandboxing, some features stopped working and I see this message in the log:

```
9/14/12 10:51:58.863 PM sandboxd[41243]: ([41237]) MouseRecorder(41237) deny hid-control
```

Is there any hidden entitlement I could use or we have no chance in the App Store with this app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I'm several years too late, I assume I can help others looking for the same. It's taken me days wondering why I couldn't connect to the keyboard. Today, the thought of the sandbox hit me, and I finally allowed my app access.

As described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html), I added the following to the `.entitlements` file, and got access.

```
<key>com.apple.security.device.usb</key>
<true/>
```

To be specific, and not mislead:

> I do not use Carbon; I use IOKit.hid, with Swift.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: See the new accepted answer

Just to answer my own question – it's not possible, there is no workaround and it's unlikely it will be possible in the future.

Comment: Does anybody know of any temporary exception entitlements? Apple does list none (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html), but it would be really nice to have a way to allow this during development without having to disable the sandbox as a whole.