# Any way for a sandboxed OS X app to intercept keystrokes?

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox, entitlements, keystrokes

So I've used Dave Delong's brilliant code here to intercept keystrokes in OS X without my app needing to be in focus, unfortunately my app crashes when I try to sandbox it with the message 'deny hid-control' in the console.

A little bit of digging turns up that as of a year ago this wasn't possible, but has anything changed since then? Or does this mean that my app can't go in the Mac App Store since it's dependent on being able to intercept keystrokes? Is there an entitlement that I'm just missing out on here?

Comment: It works now. I gave an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430449/allow-hid-control-for-the-sandboxed-app/50458076#50458076)